# How do I convert a script using mysql_ functions to use mysqli_ functions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

**EDIT:** Whether or not to use `mysqli_` is outside the scope of this question. Consider using PDO.

---

What steps need to be taken to convert a script from using the deprecated `mysql_` functions to `mysqli_`?

Is there anything that needs to be done differently when using `mysqli_` instead of `mysql`?

Here's a basic script using `mysql_` functions:

```
<?php

//define host, username and password

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_name ="db1";
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($input_string);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.col1=' . $value1 . '';
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc*$result)
{
    $col1 = $row['col1'];
    $col2 = $row['col2'];

    echo $col1 . ' ' . $col2 . '<br />';
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### **Note:** Converting from `mysql_` to [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/mysqli) may not be optimal. Consider [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) if you're prepared to convert all of your code to [OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

It can be tempting to try to replace all instances of `mysql_` with `mysqli_` and pray it works. You'd be close but not quite on point.

### **Connecting to the database:**

Fortunately, [`mysqli_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) works closely enough to `mysql_query` that you can just swap out their function names.

mysql_:

```
$con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
```

mysqli_:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
```

### **Selecting a database**

Now, with most of the other functions in the `mysqli_` library, you'll need to pass `mysqli_select_db` the database connection as its **first** parameter. Most of the `mysqli_` functions require the connection object first.

For this function, you can just switch the order of the arguments you pass to the function. If you didn't pass it a connection object before, **you have to add it as the first parameter now.**

mysql_:

```
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
```

mysqli_:

```
mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname);
```

As a bonus, you can also pass the database name as the fourth parameter to `mysqli_connect` - bypassing the need to call `mysqli_select_db`.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

### **Sanitize user input**

Using `mysqli_real_escape_string` is very similar to `mysql_real_escape_string`. You just need to pass the connection object as the first parameter.

mysql_:

```
$value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($input_string);
```

mysqli_:

```
$value1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $input_string);
```

### **Very Important: Preparing and Running a Query**

One reason the `mysql_` functions were deprecated to begin with was their inability to handle prepared statements. If you simply convert your code to `mysqli_` without taking this important step, you are subject to some of the largest weaknesses of the `mysql_` functions.

It's worth reading these articles on prepared statements and their benefits:

[Wikipedia - Prepared Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

[PHP.net - MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Note: When using prepared statements, it's best to explicitly list each column you're attempting to query, rather than using the `*` notation to query all columns. This way you can ensure you've accounted for all of the columns in your call to `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`.

mysql_:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.col1=' . $value1 . '';
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc*$result)
{
    $col1 = $row['col1'];
    $col2 = $row['col2'];

    echo $col1 . ' ' . $col2 . '<br />';
}
```

mysqli_:

```
$query = 'SELECT col1,col2 FROM table1 WHERE table1.col1=?';
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

    /* pass parameters to query */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $value1);

    /* run the query on the database */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* assign variable for each column to store results in */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2);

    /* fetch values */
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        /*
            on each fetch, the values for each column 
            in the results are automatically stored in 
            the variables we assigned using 
            "mysqli_stmt_bind_result"
        */
        echo $col1 . ' ' . $col2 . '<br />';
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

### **Showing errors**

Showing errors works a little differently with `mysqli_`. [`mysqli_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) requires the connection object as its first parameter. But what if the connection failed? `mysqli_` introduces a small set of functions that don't require the connection object: the [`mysqli_connect_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) functions.

mysql_:

```
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!$result) {
    die('SQL Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

mysqli_:

```
/* check connection error*/
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
}

/* check query error */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

    // ... execute query

    if (mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)) {
        echo 'SQL Error: ' . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no point in converting to `mysqli_` (except for deprecation warnings) if you still do string interpolation instead of prepared statements. People should move away from string interpolation.

Comment: @JanDvorak To move away from deprecated functions was the exact point of this article. Some of the beginning users out there like `mysql_` for its simplicity. This answer makes it easy to use  `mysqli_` - which is much better.

Comment: The need for string interpolation is the exact reason why `mysql_` was deprecated.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't think there is. Good catch.

Comment: @YourCommonSense nothing. That's an irrelevant factor, but I'll change it for you.

Comment: If this was to be made a definitive answer to this question, I'd suggest showing the difference between escaped input with `mysql_real_escape_string` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` (which requires a connection!) and also prepared statements.

Comment: Answer has been updated to describe usage of prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

**EXAMPLE.**

This is your dbc class

```
<?php

class dbc {

    public $dbserver = 'server';
    public $dbusername = 'user';
    public $dbpassword = 'pass';
    public $dbname = 'db';

    function openDb() {    
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("error, please try again");
        }        
        return $db;
    }

    function getAllData($qty) {
        //prepared query to prevent SQL injections
        $query = "select * from TABLE where qty = ?";
        $stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $qty, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rows;
    }    
?>
```

your PHP page:

```
<?php 
require "dbc.php";

$getList = $db->getAllData(25);

foreach ($getList as $key=> $row) {
         echo $row['columnName'] .' key: '. $key;
    }
```

Comment: I think people are getting a little dense around this question: It explicitly asks **how** to convert `mysql` to `mysqli`. Not why, or if. And certainly doesn't ask for a PDO example.

Answer (score 0):

## Do not convert mysql_ functions to mysqli_. Period.

There is not a single reason to do that.

**First, there is no reason to do that just mechanically, changing only function names leaving algorithm the same:**

Without implementing parameterized queries such a move makes very little sense.
If your only concern is "Deprecated" errors - you can just turn them off with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

and continue happily using old mysql_*
Note that you will need that only in 2-3 years, when PHP 5.5 will reach shared hostings.
So, there is no need to hurry as well.

**Second, what you really need is to eliminate all the bare API calls from the code**

encapsulating them in to some sort of abstraction library. This should be your main concern, not a particular API used in this library, which could be changed in a wink.

**Finally, the only real reason for switching from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` is parameterized queries.**

### And mysqli is totally unusable with them.

With prepared statements PDO is the only choice you have.

Let me show you what I mean.
Imagine we have an array of checkboxes from HTML form to add into query dynamically.
With PDO we can have some relatively sane and quite concise (however still uselessly complex and polluted) code:

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($_GET['cat']) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($_GET['cat']);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

### With mysqli such a trivial case will take you hours of writing and debugging several pages of extremely intricate code.

Just try it and see.

However, even PDO require some obscure and useless code to create certain query parts. So, the best way would be to use some more intelligent library, such as [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), which will do all the job internally, from binding to fetching, **making all your code into single line**:

```
$data = $db->getALL("SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IN (?a)", $_GET['cat']);
```

Comment: Can you add reasons for that?

Comment: The point of the article is to make it easy for people who are still using mysql_ functions to move away from the deprecated functions.

Comment: One major reason is preventing SQL Injection (http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: This post doesn't really answer the question, the question wasn't "Should I" or "Is it best to"? It's simply "How to". At this point, the coder has already decided to use mysqli.