# PHP script for getting data from mysql only getting a portion of the values

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get data from a mysql table and send it via a php script as a json string so it later can be used by for example ios apps.

The code i have so far is:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

mysql_select_db("FreeSir_MarinaLaroverket") or die("Unable to select database");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Nyheter");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
$arr[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

But when i use the script i get the following:

```
[{"Index":"1","Title":null,"News":null,"Date":"11\/1"},{"Index":"2","Title":"Andra nyheten","News":null,"Date":"22\/2"}]
```

As you might see there, i have some null values that pops up there from nowhere. I've doublechecked that i have the correct values inserted and all, but it still just gives me null.

I would appreciate it if anyone of you could see what is making this code not giving me all the values i want.

Best Regards

FreeSirenety

Comment: have you tried doing a `var_dump($arr)` ? to see what is inside?

Comment: as an aside, PHP functions that start with mysql_ have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the MySQLi or PDO extensions instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15055993/1270996 Look here for how to convert your script from mysql_ to mysqli_.

Comment: what result you want ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `var_dump($arr)` statement displays the correct data, so you probably have a problem with the JSON representation. Check [the manual](http://php.net/json_encode) for `json_encode()`, and look for the `$options` parameter.