# How do you link tables in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry of the question title is misleading (mods, if you can find a better title, please rename), but I couldn't really think of another way of generalizing what I am trying to do. I am programming a forum. To start off, here are my tables:

'topics' table

```
topic_id INT(8) auto_increment
topic_subject VARCHAR(255)
topic_date DATETIME
topic_cat INT(8)
topic_by INT(8)
```

'posts' table

```
post_id INT(8) auto_increment
post_content TEXT
post_date DATETIME
post_topic INT(8)
post_by int(8)
```

When someone wants to create a new topic, there are two fields they fill out (and a submit button): 'subject' and 'content'. The FORM method is POST. When they click the submit button, I am collecting the `$_POST` array data into two arrays, one called `$topic_data`(contains required information for the 'topics' table) and another called `$post_data` (contains required information for the 'posts' table). However, the problem is that the post table requires a 'post_topic' field. That field is what I want to link to the auto_incremented 'topic_id' field in the 'topics' table.

I guess the way I ask the question is; How do I insert the topic info into the 'topics' table, get the auto_incremented 'topic_id' field for that row I just inserted, and insert that into the 'post_topic' field in 'posts' along with the other post data?

Comment: So have you tried any coding to implement this yet?

Comment: Not enough to bother posting it here, since I don't really know where to start with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a MySQL query using `mysqli` or `PDO` (take your pick) to insert the topic into the `topics` table. Then use [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) or [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) to get the topic id of the last inserted topic. Use this value to insert the post into your `posts` table.

Comment: I am the using mysql_query() function to insert. Can I do something similar, or is there an easy way to convert to mysqli? I have never touched it before

Comment: You really should not be using the `mysql_` functions. They are going to be deprecated soon, and are not as secure (since they do not allow parameter binding). Anyways, since you are using them, you can use [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Can you help me find a way to convert all my mysql_ functions to mysqli? Anyways, that will help tremendously. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read this [tutorial on PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/), and re-write all your database queries.

Comment: Just so I understand clearly, `mysql_insert_id()` returns the integer value of the last mysql query?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. From the docs `Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query`

Comment: Also, read this link to convert your code away from `mysql_` functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055990/how-do-i-convert-a-script-using-mysql-functions-to-use-mysqli-functions/15055993#15055993