# mysqli fetching multiple rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to convert over to mysqli and as expected, I am running into difficulties.

I have created a login script as follow, which works and I think is correct. (I know the passwords need to be hashed, I just want to get it up and running first)

```
//  POST variables
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username required';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password required';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: logon.php");
    exit();
}

//prepared statements

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM auth WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")) {
$stmt->execute();

/* bind variables to prepared statement */
$stmt->bind_result($user, $pass);

/* fetch values */
$stmt->fetch();
if ($user == $username && $pass == $password)
{
    printf("Welcome %s", $user);
}
else
{
    printf("Login failed");
}


/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I would like to set my session variables if the login passes, previously with mysqll I did the following

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM auth WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        //Set session variables
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['ID'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['fname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD'] = $member['password'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_AUTH_LEVEL'] = $member['auth_level'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name or password not found';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: logon.php");
            exit();
```

I think my problem is "$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);" how do I do this in mysqli ? As my prepared statement is only binding the username and password, previously I used a SELECT * FROM

Thanks

Comment: See the examples at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php, it has a fecth_assoc array in it.

Comment: [You've been told already that there is no point in moving to mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921090/moving-to-mysqli). Move to PDO prepared statements instead. Or just keep mysql

Comment: I have researched and it would seem Mysqli meets my requirments, why change to PDO ?? I asked for assistance on mysqli , I have clearly decided to use mysqli ... it is not deprecated, it is supported.

Comment: There is an error in your prepared statement.  You have variable names instead of the required ?.  Your if ensures it will simply do nothing rather than returning an error.   The server I use doesn't have PDO installed so I have to use mysqli!  BTW you don't HAVE to use prepared statements straight away.  They don't suit all purposes and are resource-hungry.  You could start with a simple conversion with a batch replace function.  Get it working with that then work on the sql line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to use functions: **[`$mysqli->query(string)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)**, **[`$mysqli_result->num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)** and **[`$mysqli_result->fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)**

Your code could look like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);

$qry = "SELECT * FROM auth WHERE username=? AND password=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['ID'];
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
...
```

---

Not directly related to your question here, but you might want to correctly use prepared statements by replacing those two lines:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM auth WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    ...
```

with these:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM auth WHERE username=? AND password=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    ...
```

Comment: Great thanks, I will give it a go (btw I didnt go near votes)

Comment: This dosnt use my prepared statement though, I want to use prepares statements to prevent SQL injection also. Should I run two seperate queries ?

Comment: @Gary: Answer updated with prepared statements. You don't need to run separate queries if you can get all necessary data with one.